# Launching Error occurs in XML When Executing in TestNG - Unable to continue with test execution - Selenium

Tags: java, maven, selenium-webdriver

I would like to ask for your help on the problem I am encountering when executing the XML in TestNG.

Here is my XML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Local cwsSprint1-Desktop Test" verbose="0" parallel="false">
 <listeners>
  <listener class-name="com.quantum.listeners.QuantumReportiumListener" />
 </listeners>

 <parameter name="driver.name" value="chromeDriver" />
 <parameter name="webdriver.chrome.driver" value="driver/chromedriver.exe" />
 <parameter name="chrome.additional.capabilities" value="{'chromeOptions':{'useAutomationExtension':false}}"/>
 <!-- <parameter name="chrome.additional.capabilities" value="{'chromeOptions':{'mobileEmulation':{'deviceName':'Galaxy S III'}}}" />
 <parameter name="chrome.additional.capabilities" value="{'chromeOptions':{'mobileEmulation':{'deviceName':'iPhone 6/7/8'}}}" /> 
  -->
  
 <!-- Locally testing web application on desktop -->
 <test name="cwsSprint1-Desktop" enabled="true">
  <groups>
   <run>
    <!-- <include name="@LoginMenu"/> -->
    <include name="@ViewPrimaryNavigationMenuDesktop"/>
    <!-- <include name="@PolicyCardsDesktop"/> -->
   </run>
  </groups>

  <classes>
   <class name="com.qmetry.qaf.automation.step.client.gherkin.GherkinScenarioFactory" />
  </classes>
 </test>
</suite>
```

Here is the error:

```html
An internal error occurred during: "Launching cws-regional_src.main.resources.config.cwsXMLFilesFunctional.Sprint 1.cwsSprint1 - Desktop.xml".
org.testng.eclipse.maven.MavenTestNGLaunchConfigurationProvider.getClasspath(Lorg/eclipse/debug/core/ILaunchConfiguration;)Ljava/util/List;
```

Comment: I already tried to update all necessary addins in eclipse, resintall projects and jdk but still experiencing this error, any idea why?

Comment: I notice the error references maven; could you add your pom.xml to the question?

Comment: I can't saved edits when adding the pom. because it's too long, there is an error that my post is mostly code